# Magento 2 : Exception Error Depricated Functionality Return type

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I am using `magento version 2.4.2` and `php version 7.4.3`

I am trying to run the project locally, getting the below error:

```
Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Return type of Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Config/FileIterator.php on line 68 in /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Config/FileIterator.php(17): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler() #1 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(576): include('...') #2 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(427): Composer\Autoload\{closure}() #3 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Config/FileIteratorFactory.php(38): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() #4 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Dir/Reader.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\FileIteratorFactory->create() #5 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Dir/Reader.php(86): Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader->getFilesIterator() #6 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/FileResolver.php(65): Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader->getConfigurationFiles() #7 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config/FileResolver/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\FileResolver->get() #8 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(128): Magento\Framework\App\Config\FileResolver\Proxy->get() #9 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/App/ResourceConnection/Config/Reader.php(59): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read() #10 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Config/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Config\Reader->read() #11 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Data/Scoped.php(119): Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Config\Reader\Proxy->read() #12 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Data/Scoped.php(97): Magento\Framework\Config\Data\Scoped->_loadScopedData() #13 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/App/ResourceConnection/Config.php(68): Magento\Framework\Config\Data\Scoped->get() #14 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Config/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Config->getConnectionName() #15 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/App/ResourceConnection.php(96): Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Config\Proxy->getConnectionName() #16 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Lock/Backend/Database.php(82): Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection->getConnection() #17 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/LockGuardedCacheLoader.php(134): Magento\Framework\Lock\Backend\Database->lock() #18 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(281): Magento\Framework\Cache\LockGuardedCacheLoader->lockedLoadData() #19 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(207): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData() #20 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(181): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->getWithParts() #21 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(132): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get() #22 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get() #23 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(93): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue() #24 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Config.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag() #25 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Plugin/HttpPlugin.php(49): Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config->isNewRelicEnabled() #26 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\NewRelicReporting\Plugin\HttpPlugin->beforeCatchException() #27 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() #28 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins() #29 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(269): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->catchException() #30 /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() #31 {main}
```

If anyone has any idea how to fix this issue, please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP version 8.1 we have to put the return type.

But you are using the PHP 7.4.3, this issue seems to be not Occured.

There are two possible solutions:

check the versions compatibility with the Magento version

Or you can use the lower version of the PHP

Comment: I can see PHP 7.4 is compatible with Magento 2.4.2 but still why i am getting this error?

Comment: I also checked this, before answering you, but try once with the 7.3

Comment: No, it's not working with 7.3

Comment: try run composer update command

Comment: Tried but same error Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /var/www/html/prodmagerepo/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 34

Comment: rename the vendor and then run composer install

Comment: No it's not working. Same error.

Comment: have you installed the php fpm with the all required extenions?

Comment: yes, but same error

Comment: Remove composer.local and then run composer install, if then not working fine then run composer update, now surely it will works fine